# How do I show all the items in the favorites list using the room database?

Tags: android, android-room

By examining various examples, I added to favorites when the item on Recyclerview was clicked. But I have a problem and I couldn't fix it.

When I click on add favorite, the item goes to the favorites list, but the last item I clicked is on the list. I want all the elements I click to appear in the list.

My Dao class

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Country country);

@Delete
void delete(Country country);

@Query("SELECT * FROM followed_country")
LiveData<List<Country>> getAllFavoriteCountries();
```

My click method in my adapter class

```
    mListItemBinding.imgFollowedCountry.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int position = getLayoutPosition();
                final Country country = countryList.get(position);
                if (isChecked && !isCountryFavorite(country)) {
                    final CountryDatabase db = CountryDatabase.getInstance(context);
                    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("EKLENDİ", "EKLENDİİİİİ");
                            db.countryDao().insert(country);
                        }
                    });
                    mListItemBinding.imgFollowedCountry.setChecked(true);
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    final CountryDatabase db = CountryDatabase.getInstance(context);
                    AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            db.countryDao().delete(country);
                        }
                    });
                    mListItemBinding.imgFollowedCountry.setChecked(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

FavoriteActivity class

```
    FavoriteViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FavoriteViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getFavoriteCountry().observe(this, new Observer<List<Country>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Country> countryList) {
            adapter.setCountry(countryList);
            Log.e("MAİNN", ""+countryList.size());
        }
    });
```

FavoriteViewModel Class

```
private LiveData<List<Country>> country;

public FavoriteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    CountryDatabase db = CountryDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplication());
    country = db.countryDao().getAllFavoriteCountries();
}

public LiveData<List<Country>> getFavoriteCountry(){
    return country;
}
```

Some screenshots

[image: I added 2 items to my favorites on the list]

[image: But only the last item I added is visible]

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to add another column to your data class. lets assume your data class is `Country`, you can redefine it as follows

```
class Country{
   String name;
   Long population;
   Boolean isFavorite; //this is the added column
}
```

After that all what you will do is toggle the `isFavorite` flag to `true` or `false` depending on whether the country has been favorited or not. In Kotlin you can use a default value to always set it to false when a new `Country` is created.

Your `Dao` class will now look like this

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Country country);

@Delete
void delete(Country country);

@Query("SELECT * FROM followed_country where isFavorite=true")
LiveData<List<Country>> getAllFavoriteCountries();
```

I don't know if my syntax for the `@Query` is accurate but I hope you get the big picture now.

Comment: @ihaydinn You have to perform an update on the original object and save it back to the database with the isFavorite flag toggled. only then will your query return a result\